# Div stick near the top of the page on scroll and stop at footer - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I found this code http://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/1/ . It fits almost perfectly for me. but I want the div stopped at the footer. What code you have to insert there? Thank you for your help.

```
function fixDiv() {
var $div = $("#navwrap");
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
    $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}); 
}
else {
    $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'width': '100%'});
}
```

}

```
$("#navwrap").data("top", $("#navwrap").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the div stopped at the footer" ??

Comment: I want to stick div #navwrap stopped at footer. Chceck this http://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/441/

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you need this functionality, still your working demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/445/)

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {       
             $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'absolute', 'bottom': '0px','top':'auto', 'width': '100%'}); 
}
```

hope you are looking for this.

Comment: This code is working good, but i want to stop #navwrap when reach specific point like #footer

Comment: i dont understand what you really need.check this fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/Kkv7X/

Comment: Something like this http://codepen.io/jakestuts/full/EzKau , this example show that float div stops at end of post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#navwrap");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) {
        $('#navwrap').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0',
            'width': '100%'
        });
    } if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $('#navwrap').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'bottom': '0',
            'top'   :  'auto',
            'width': '100%'
        });
    }
}
$("#navwrap").data("top", $("#navwrap").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nj4Q8/